# StreamReader file how to ONLY update when high score is reached in listbox?

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

How do I write my `StreamReader` file where it will ONLY override the game(s) high score if it is over the current high score? Currently all scores are being updated to the listbox instead of just the scores that exceed the current score/txt file.

Thanks in Advance

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int Dice;
    int RunningTotal;
    int MaxRolls;
    int RollCount;
    Random rand = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RollDiebutton.Enabled = true;
        StartOverbutton.Enabled = true;
        ClickBeginGametoStartlabel.Visible = false;
        int beginTotal = 0;
        TotalMoneyEarnedlabel.Text = beginTotal.ToString("c");

        MaxRolls = rand.Next(3) + 2;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)         
    {
        try
        {
            string highScore;
            StreamReader inputFile; 

            inputFile = File.OpenText("Highscore.txt"); 
            HighscoreBox.Items.Clear();

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                highScore = inputFile.ReadLine();   
                HighscoreBox.Items.Add(highScore);
            }

            inputFile.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        RollDiebutton.Enabled = false;
        BeginGamebutton.Enabled = true;
        StartOverbutton.Enabled = false;
        TotalMoneyEarnedlabel.Text = "";

        BeginpictureBox.Image = P2Kbembow.Properties.Resources.Begin;
        Pressyourluckandrollagainlabel.Visible = false;
        ClickBeginGametoStartlabel.Visible = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Close Form
        this.Close();
    }

    private void RollDiebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Dice = rand.Next(6) + 1;

        RunningTotal += 0;
        int DollarAmount = 100;
        int Sum = (Dice * DollarAmount);

        BeginGamebutton.Enabled = false;
        Pressyourluckandrollagainlabel.Visible = true;

        RunningTotal += Sum;
        TotalMoneyEarnedlabel.Text = RunningTotal.ToString("c");
        RollCount += 1;

        if (MaxRolls == 0)
        {
            Random getMax = new Random();
            TotalMoneyEarnedlabel.Text = ""; 
        }
        else
            if (RollCount >= MaxRolls)
            {
                MaxRolls = 6;
                RollCount = 0;
                RunningTotal = 0;

                TotalMoneyEarnedlabel.Text = "$0.0";
                Show(); MessageBox.Show("Sorry! You lose!");

                RollDiebutton.Enabled = false;
                BeginGamebutton.Enabled = true;

                TotalMoneyEarnedlabel.Text = "";

                BeginpictureBox.Image = P2Kbembow.Properties.Resources.Begin;
                Pressyourluckandrollagainlabel.Visible = false;
                ClickBeginGametoStartlabel.Visible = true;
                StartOverbutton.Enabled = false;

                return;
            }

        StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.CreateText("HighScore.txt");

        outputFile.WriteLine(TotalMoneyEarnedlabel.Text);
        outputFile.Close();

        if (Dice == 1)
        {
            //shows Image of dice 1
            BeginpictureBox.Image = P2Kbembow.Properties.Resources._1Die;
        }

        if (Dice == 2)
        {
            //shows Image of dice 2
            BeginpictureBox.Image = P2Kbembow.Properties.Resources._2Die;
        }

        if (Dice == 3)
        {
            //shows Image of dice 3
            BeginpictureBox.Image = P2Kbembow.Properties.Resources._3Die;
        }
        if (Dice == 4)
        {
            //shows Image of dice 4
            BeginpictureBox.Image = P2Kbembow.Properties.Resources._4Die;
        }

        if (Dice == 5)
        {
            //shows Image of dice 5
            BeginpictureBox.Image = P2Kbembow.Properties.Resources._5Die;
        }

        if (Dice == 6)
        {
            //shows Image of dice 6
            BeginpictureBox.Image = P2Kbembow.Properties.Resources._6Die;
        }

        //Display Message Box of dice rolled 
        Show(); MessageBox.Show(" You rolled a  " + Dice + "!");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string highScore;
            StreamReader inputFile;

            inputFile = File.OpenText("Highscore.txt");
            HighscoreBox.Items.Clear();

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                highScore = inputFile.ReadLine();
                HighscoreBox.Items.Add(highScore);

            }

            inputFile.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: _override games high my HighscoreBox High score_ ? i couldnt understand this..what is your criteria for the high score?

Comment: you want to overwrite the highscore value on the text file?

Comment: Sorry I believe I edited where I dont sound like such an idiot haha. But pretty much If the current new total is greater than the previous high score shown on the form or my txt file I created, I need the game to overwrite the new total high score to the text file so it will be shown on the form thereafter

Comment: Yes Codelgnoto this is correct, where only the high score will be updated to the txt file and show on my program on new games.

Comment: @cpkob I think you want to show only the highest score from text file to listbox?Currently you are adding every single score to your listbox

Comment: Yes, How would I accomplish that?

Comment: @cpkob its pretty trivial. Do you have only one score as in integer figures in each line of your file?

Comment: Yes, I have written a random high score in a .txt file that is preloaded into the game and just need it to update .txt and listbox showing ONLY when the score has been beaten but simply cant figure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

The problematic part of your code is very trivial. To add only the highest score from your file to listbox you could just use:

```
var highScore = File.ReadAllLines("Highscore.txt").Max(score => decimal.Parse(score));
HighscoreBox.Items.Clear();
HighscoreBox.Items.Add(highScore);
```

But there are a number of other things you have to take care of:

1. You have to ensure there is a valid highscore sheet available. So check that in Form load (*and may be you dont require to create and overwrite the existing file every time on rolling the die*).
2. [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) your code to load the high score from file to listbox.

   ```
   string _fileName = "Highscore.txt";

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (!File.Exists(_fileName))
       {
           File.Create(_fileName);
           return; 
       }

       LoadHighestScore();
   }

   private void LoadHighestScore()
   {
       HighscoreBox.Items.Clear();

       var highestScore = GetHighestScore();
       HighscoreBox.Items.Add(highestScore);
   }

   private decimal GetHighestScore()
   {
       var scores = File.ReadAllLines(_fileName);
       if (scores.Length == 0)
           return 0;

       return scores.Max(score => decimal.Parse(score));
   }
   ```
3. You can write the score to your file every time upon rolling the die like this:

   ```
   private void RollDiebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //-------------------------
       //-------------------------

       WriteScore(score);

       //-------------------------
       //-------------------------
   }

   private void WriteScore(string score)
   {
       File.AppendAllLines(sd, new string[]{ score });
   }
   ```

Mind you this `appends` the scores to your file every time. If you need to write only if the score beats the existing highest score (which is  not very clear from your question) you could do:

```
    private void WriteScore(string score)
    {
        if (int.Parse(score) > GetHighestScore())
            File.AppendAllLines(sd, new string[]{ score });
    }
```

1. Please break down your large section of code to different methods so that it aids code reuse. Even better if you can move the logics to a different class.
2. To do this kind of thing, its better to use a small lightweight client database like SQLite. In future what if you need more complex operation like "highest score for every user" ? To get the max score you could do:

   ```
   SELECT MAX(score) FROM highscores;
   ```

As simple as that.

Lastly please post the problematic section of your code rather than whole bunch of irrelevant lines.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but using that seemed to not work in my file it crashes my program. Is there any other advice you can lend me? in simplest form where only the high score would reflect. And sorry for so much code. I am a super beginner in programming.

Comment: @cpkob where does it crash? In which line? Tell us the crash message. Without all these its impossible to tell you. I just ran the above code myself and see no crashing.